# Getting tslint warning on performing bit-wise and

Tags: tslint

I am performing bit-wise and operation and checking result with some other value using === in typescript code.

```
(res & 2) === 2
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

TSLint is a linter for TypeScript, meaning it's a separate library that checks for best practices in your code. In most *(but not all)* projects, bitwise operations like `|` or `&` are typos in code that was meant to be `||` or `&&`. See https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-bitwise.

If you do intend to do a `|`, disable the `no-bitwise` rule in your tslint.json: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/